# Send Referer http header with android MediaPlayer request

Tags: android, header, request, media-player, http-referer

Is it possible to add a "Referer" header to be sent together with the request for the data using android MediaPlayer?

I'm doing something like that:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();

headers.put("User-Agent", "xxx");
headers.put("Referer", "http://yyy");
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(myContext, myUri, headers);
mp.prepareAsync();
```

and I'm using a proxy to monitor all HTTP traffic. The "User-Agent" header is sent and all other headers I have tried with, however, "Referer" header is never sent.

It is necessary to send a "Referer" header to play the remote files I want, since otherwise the server answer with a 403 forbidden error status code.

Comment: Hello, I'm running the same issue, what did you do ?!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find a solution :-(

Comment: Thank you for your reply :-) Try with "user-agent" header, the "referer" spoof doesn't work even with advanced tools.

Comment: If you're on Android 4.X, the problem is specific to *that* version. I don't know why. My (same) code works on 2.X, 3.X and 5.X, but 4.X strips custom headers (at least on the `MediaPlayer` class). I don't know about a solution on 4.X; your code should work on Android 2/3/5 though. [I asked a question about 4.X stripping headers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31792681/1986871).